# :root CSS selector inside Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, css-variables

Why CSS variables (CSS Custom properties) declared with the :root selector inside the shadow DOM, are not being applied ?

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let shadow = container.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

shadow.innerHTML=`
  <style>
      :root{
          --my-color : red;
      }
      span{
          color: var(--my-color);
      }
  </style>
  <span>I SHOULD BE RED</span>
`;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I don't consider this question is a duplicate, i didn't ask **how** to declare CSS variables in a shadow DOM, but **why** the :root selector does not work in the shadow DOM